# Converting BIGINT to display as Nvarchar Column

Tags: sql, casting, type-conversion, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to edit a query for a report that has already been setup for reporting, however I'm running into some issues trying to convert a BigInt (USERID) column to a Nvarchar(150) (FIRST_NAME) column from another table for one particular change I need to make to the query as a whole.

Table Structure is as follows (Removed some unnecessary columns, as essentially the only columns that are important are "USERID, REPORTINGTO)

Table A (SDU)

```
USERID  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    REPORTINGTO
28      Name 28     Surname 28  NULL
29      Name 29     Surname 29  36
30      Name 30     Surname 30  40
31      Name 31     Surname 31  53211
32      Name 32     Surname 32  40
33      Name 33     Surname 33  53211
34      Name 34     Surname 34  NULL
35      Name 35     Surname 35  40
36      Name 36     Surname 36  26
```

Table B (AAAUSER)

```
USER_ID FIRST_NAME
34  Name 34
35  Name 35
36  Name 36
```

In the REPORTINGTO column it is pulling the USERID, which is referencing the correct manager, but is not suitable for the report purposes; we need to display "FIRST_NAME" from Table B. (first_name IS different to FirstName in table A)

```
select
    au.FIRST_NAME 'Tech'
    ,sdu.JOBTITLE 'Title'
    ,sdu.REPORTINGTO 'Manager'

from 

AaaUser au
    join HelpDeskCrew hdc on au.USER_ID = hdc.TECHNICIANID
    join SDUser sdu on au.USER_ID = sdu.USERID
```

This outputs the table as

```
Tech        Title                       Manager
Full Name 1 Senior Technical Consultant 26
Full Name 2 Senior Technical Consultant 53211
```

Whereas I want Manager to display as "FIRST_NAME" from Table B; as opposed to the "USERID" associated with that Manager.

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. It seems Cast/Convert is the way to go, but as of yet I've been unable to input that with any success.

Comment: I've edited your data to reformat it so the data aligns with the column headers. Please update it if it is not correct, because your post is rather harder to understand without this alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from joining the same table in twice:

```
select
    sdi.USERID as TechID
    ,au.FIRST_NAME as TechName
    ,sdu.JOBTITLE as Title
    ,sdu.REPORTINGTO as ManagerID
    ,mu.FIRST_NAME as ManagerName
from 
    SDUser sdu
    INNER JOIN AaaUser au on au.USER_ID = sdu.USERID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AaaUser mu on mu.USER_ID = sdu.REPORTINGTO
```

Tips:

- I removed helpdeskcrew as you didn't seem to use it, and i didnt want extra visual clutter of a table that was not defined - feel free to add it back in
- Sometimes manager id in sdu is null, so when joining the Aaauser table in for manager name it must be left joined otherwise those rows will disappear
- Do not use ' around column name aliases. In SQL, ' is for strings, and " (or nothing) is for identifiers
- You can join a table into a query as many times as you want, and indeed you should, if the main table references that table for multiple different reasons
- You have to join it in multiple times for different reasons; you cannot OR a single use of the table. Join it in multiple times and give each table an alias that describes the purpose - here I used `au` for the normal user (because you did) and `mu` for "managinguser" - i.e the manager who manages the user

Comment: Thanks! The helpdeskcrew was a part of the larger query so I added it back in! Thanks for the additional comments regarding joining the same table into a query multiple times as well, will use this more in future.